# Child image not growing in parent

Tags: html, css, image, css-position, tailwind-css

I've got this social card on my website (I use [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="rounded-lg overflow-hidden mb-6 cursor-pointer bg-white h-auto" style="box-shadow: lightgrey 4px 4px 12px;">
    <div class="no-underline text-black overflow-hidden h-full relative"><img src="https://say-hi-dog.imgix.net/sayhidog/2179/posts/rDkbVVVGPNe11hTHTl7M6aV5V8emT8MJQ2yIepq7.jpeg?w=1200&amp;h=1200&amp;dpr=1&amp;fit=max&amp;auto=format" class="bg-gray-200 absolute h-full">
        <div class="w-12 h-12 bg-second absolute">
            <div>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                    <path d="M6.642 15.096c-.5 0-1-.132-1.43-.37-.108-.061-.21-.135-.306-.198a2.394 2.394 0 01-.24-.205c-.057-.057-.336-.478-.38-.48a2.729 2.729 0 01-1.846-.994l-2.4 4.359c-.125.228.078.494.354.463l3.075-.344 1.565 2.505c.139.223.488.214.614-.014l2.442-4.432a2.51 2.51 0 01-.758-.38c-.22.059-.45.09-.69.09zm8.913-2.247c-.082.1-.174.195-.272.285a2.701 2.701 0 01-1.576.707c-.043.004-.32.425-.38.482-.118.113-.246.205-.388.31-.05.021-.102.063-.157.092a2.956 2.956 0 01-1.43.374c-.24 0-.473-.032-.69-.093-.22.164-.477.292-.758.38l2.442 4.432c.125.228.477.237.614.014l1.565-2.505 3.074.344c.277.031.48-.235.354-.463l-2.398-4.359zm-1.926-2.685c.183-.256.34-.527.47-.808a4.69 4.69 0 000-3.933 4.995 4.995 0 00-1.18-1.605 5.567 5.567 0 00-1.75-1.084 5.888 5.888 0 00-2.197-.396c-.743 0-1.465.134-2.143.396a5.493 5.493 0 00-1.75 1.084A5.063 5.063 0 003.9 5.423a4.69 4.69 0 000 3.933 5.02 5.02 0 001.18 1.608 5.568 5.568 0 001.75 1.084 5.876 5.876 0 001.846.39c.214.01.431.01.646 0a5.876 5.876 0 001.848-.39 5.493 5.493 0 001.75-1.084 5.3 5.3 0 00.71-.8zM9.442 4.688c.197-.625.793-1.015 1.332-.872.539.142.815.765.619 1.39-.196.624-.793 1.014-1.332.872-.537-.143-.815-.766-.619-1.39zm-2.218-.872c.54-.143 1.135.247 1.332.872.196.624-.082 1.247-.62 1.39-.538.142-1.134-.248-1.33-.873-.2-.624.08-1.247.618-1.39zM5.107 7.417c-.268-.601-.064-1.247.454-1.442.519-.195 1.156.136 1.426.738.267.601.064 1.247-.455 1.442-.518.195-1.156-.136-1.425-.738zm5.242 2.954c-.818-.205-1.754-.18-2.579-.025l-.119.025c-.438.11-1.434-.073-1.235-.914.198-.84 1.075-.805 1.315-1.937.071-.333.236-.663.546-.864.304-.197.713-.247 1.07-.16.267.066.5.217.66.424.136.179.216.388.262.6.24 1.134 1.117 1.096 1.316 1.937.196.84-.8 1.023-1.236.914zm1.117-2.216c-.518-.195-.724-.84-.454-1.442.267-.602.904-.933 1.425-.738.518.195.724.84.454 1.442-.27.602-.906.933-1.425.738z"></path>
                    <path d="M10.625 14.252c.069 0 .14.01.208.033.804.262 1.837-.132 2.2-.838.1-.195.306-.321.54-.33.851-.035 1.644-.76 1.69-1.54a.562.562 0 01.351-.483c.77-.337 1.197-1.285.91-2.02a.537.537 0 01.127-.583c.576-.579.576-1.606.01-2.187a.532.532 0 01-.124-.57c.286-.738-.144-1.686-.914-2.02a.571.571 0 01-.358-.494c-.018-.356-.203-.742-.544-1.054a1.85 1.85 0 00-1.135-.497.614.614 0 01-.525-.323c-.167-.319-.496-.608-.935-.776a2.107 2.107 0 00-.742-.14c-.187 0-.366.027-.528.08a.685.685 0 01-.637-.118C9.933.151 9.502 0 9.022 0h-.05c-.48 0-.91.15-1.195.392a.663.663 0 01-.635.117c-.16-.052-.34-.08-.528-.08-.24 0-.493.045-.742.141-.439.168-.768.455-.934.776a.62.62 0 01-.526.323 1.85 1.85 0 00-1.135.497c-.34.312-.525.698-.544 1.054a.58.58 0 01-.358.495c-.77.333-1.2 1.28-.914 2.019a.532.532 0 01-.123.57c-.57.58-.567 1.608.009 2.187.157.159.205.381.128.582-.288.736.139 1.684.909 2.021.205.09.34.275.352.483.045.78.838 1.505 1.69 1.54.233.01.439.137.54.33.024.048.052.094.084.14l.04.057c.44.58 1.35.878 2.077.641a.656.656 0 01.621.111c.327.269.773.392 1.209.386.457.006.886-.117 1.213-.386a.658.658 0 01.415-.144zm-1.603-1.074a6.91 6.91 0 01-2.504-.455 6.302 6.302 0 01-2.003-1.24 5.777 5.777 0 01-1.352-1.84 5.344 5.344 0 01-.496-2.255c0-.782.167-1.539.496-2.254a5.73 5.73 0 011.352-1.838 6.402 6.402 0 012.003-1.241A6.767 6.767 0 019.022 1.6c.852 0 1.681.153 2.458.455a6.301 6.301 0 012.003 1.24 5.823 5.823 0 011.352 1.84c.33.712.496 1.47.496 2.253 0 .782-.167 1.539-.496 2.254a5.453 5.453 0 01-.539.924 6 6 0 01-.813.916 6.387 6.387 0 01-2.006 1.241 6.734 6.734 0 01-2.117.447c-.112.004-.224.008-.338.008z"></path>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col pt-4">
        <div class="flex px-4">
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center w-1/6 mr-2">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://sayhi.dog/profile.png" class="lozad bg-gray-400 bg-cover w-12 h-12 rounded-full shadow-lg z-50 m-2 zoom"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="px-2 pt-2 w-5/6">
                <header class="flex flex-col">
                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between"><a href="#" class="font-bold text-black no-underline">
                                Jamie
                            </a>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://sayhidog.test/og/post/221" target="_blank" class="flex my-2 rounded text-sm">
                            <p class="flex items-center text-facebook font-bold"><span class="hidden md:flex">Deel</span>
                                <div class="w-4 h-4 fill-current ml-2">
                                    <div>
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                            <path d="M5.08 12.16A2.99 2.99 0 0 1 0 10a3 3 0 0 1 5.08-2.16l8.94-4.47a3 3 0 1 1 .9 1.79L5.98 9.63a3.03 3.03 0 0 1 0 .74l8.94 4.47A2.99 2.99 0 0 1 20 17a3 3 0 1 1-5.98-.37l-8.94-4.47z"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!---->
                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between my-1">
                        <div class="flex items-center">
                            <div class="w-4 h-4 mr-1 fill-current text-gray-700">
                                <div>
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                        <path d="M1 4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h14a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4zm2 2v12h14V6H3zm2-6h2v2H5V0zm8 0h2v2h-2V0zM5 9h2v2H5V9zm0 4h2v2H5v-2zm4-4h2v2H9V9zm0 4h2v2H9v-2zm4-4h2v2h-2V9zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                            </div> <span class="text-xs text-gray-600">

                                </span></div>
                        <!---->
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex items-center my-1">
                        <div class="w-4 h-4 mr-1 fill-current text-gray-700">
                            <div>
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                    <path d="M10 20S3 10.87 3 7a7 7 0 1 1 14 0c0 3.87-7 13-7 13zm0-11a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div> <a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=51.3234,4.94846" target="_blank" class="text-xs text-gray-600">
                                Amsterdam
                            </a></div>
                </header>
                <article class="py-4 text-black">
                    Lekker lopen op de wei van mijn paardjes
                </article>
                <footer class="flex text-sm border-t">
                    <div class="block flex px-4 py-2 items-center">
                        <div>
                            <div class="w-6 h-6 fill-current hover:text-red-500 cursor-pointer zoom text-gray-500">
                                <div>
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                        <path d="M10 3.22l-.61-.6a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78 7.77L10 18.78l8.39-8.4a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78-7.77l-.61.61z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> <span class="ml-2">2</span></div>
                    <div class="block flex px-4 py-2 items-center group cursor-pointer">
                        <div class="w-6 h-6 fill-current text-gray-500 group-hover:text-gray-700 zoom">
                            <div>
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                    <path d="M17 11v3l-3-3H8a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h10a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v7a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-1zm-3 2v2a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H6l-3 3v-3H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h2v3a4 4 0 0 0 4 4h6z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div> <span class="ml-2">0 reacties</span></div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!---->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would except it to look like this:

[image]

Why does the parent not grow, while the child (image) is present?

```
<div class="no-underline text-black overflow-hidden h-full relative">
    <img src="https://say-hi-dog.imgix.net/sayhidog/2179/posts/rDkbVVVGPNe11hTHTl7M6aV5V8emT8MJQ2yIepq7.jpeg?w=1200&amp;h=1200&amp;dpr=1&amp;fit=max&amp;auto=format" class="bg-gray-200 absolute h-full">
    <div class="w-12 h-12 bg-second absolute">
        <div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                <path d="M6.642 15.096c-.5 0-1-.132-1.43-.37-.108-.061-.21-.135-.306-.198a2.394 2.394 0 01-.24-.205c-.057-.057-.336-.478-.38-.48a2.729 2.729 0 01-1.846-.994l-2.4 4.359c-.125.228.078.494.354.463l3.075-.344 1.565 2.505c.139.223.488.214.614-.014l2.442-4.432a2.51 2.51 0 01-.758-.38c-.22.059-.45.09-.69.09zm8.913-2.247c-.082.1-.174.195-.272.285a2.701 2.701 0 01-1.576.707c-.043.004-.32.425-.38.482-.118.113-.246.205-.388.31-.05.021-.102.063-.157.092a2.956 2.956 0 01-1.43.374c-.24 0-.473-.032-.69-.093-.22.164-.477.292-.758.38l2.442 4.432c.125.228.477.237.614.014l1.565-2.505 3.074.344c.277.031.48-.235.354-.463l-2.398-4.359zm-1.926-2.685c.183-.256.34-.527.47-.808a4.69 4.69 0 000-3.933 4.995 4.995 0 00-1.18-1.605 5.567 5.567 0 00-1.75-1.084 5.888 5.888 0 00-2.197-.396c-.743 0-1.465.134-2.143.396a5.493 5.493 0 00-1.75 1.084A5.063 5.063 0 003.9 5.423a4.69 4.69 0 000 3.933 5.02 5.02 0 001.18 1.608 5.568 5.568 0 001.75 1.084 5.876 5.876 0 001.846.39c.214.01.431.01.646 0a5.876 5.876 0 001.848-.39 5.493 5.493 0 001.75-1.084 5.3 5.3 0 00.71-.8zM9.442 4.688c.197-.625.793-1.015 1.332-.872.539.142.815.765.619 1.39-.196.624-.793 1.014-1.332.872-.537-.143-.815-.766-.619-1.39zm-2.218-.872c.54-.143 1.135.247 1.332.872.196.624-.082 1.247-.62 1.39-.538.142-1.134-.248-1.33-.873-.2-.624.08-1.247.618-1.39zM5.107 7.417c-.268-.601-.064-1.247.454-1.442.519-.195 1.156.136 1.426.738.267.601.064 1.247-.455 1.442-.518.195-1.156-.136-1.425-.738zm5.242 2.954c-.818-.205-1.754-.18-2.579-.025l-.119.025c-.438.11-1.434-.073-1.235-.914.198-.84 1.075-.805 1.315-1.937.071-.333.236-.663.546-.864.304-.197.713-.247 1.07-.16.267.066.5.217.66.424.136.179.216.388.262.6.24 1.134 1.117 1.096 1.316 1.937.196.84-.8 1.023-1.236.914zm1.117-2.216c-.518-.195-.724-.84-.454-1.442.267-.602.904-.933 1.425-.738.518.195.724.84.454 1.442-.27.602-.906.933-1.425.738z"></path>
                <path d="M10.625 14.252c.069 0 .14.01.208.033.804.262 1.837-.132 2.2-.838.1-.195.306-.321.54-.33.851-.035 1.644-.76 1.69-1.54a.562.562 0 01.351-.483c.77-.337 1.197-1.285.91-2.02a.537.537 0 01.127-.583c.576-.579.576-1.606.01-2.187a.532.532 0 01-.124-.57c.286-.738-.144-1.686-.914-2.02a.571.571 0 01-.358-.494c-.018-.356-.203-.742-.544-1.054a1.85 1.85 0 00-1.135-.497.614.614 0 01-.525-.323c-.167-.319-.496-.608-.935-.776a2.107 2.107 0 00-.742-.14c-.187 0-.366.027-.528.08a.685.685 0 01-.637-.118C9.933.151 9.502 0 9.022 0h-.05c-.48 0-.91.15-1.195.392a.663.663 0 01-.635.117c-.16-.052-.34-.08-.528-.08-.24 0-.493.045-.742.141-.439.168-.768.455-.934.776a.62.62 0 01-.526.323 1.85 1.85 0 00-1.135.497c-.34.312-.525.698-.544 1.054a.58.58 0 01-.358.495c-.77.333-1.2 1.28-.914 2.019a.532.532 0 01-.123.57c-.57.58-.567 1.608.009 2.187.157.159.205.381.128.582-.288.736.139 1.684.909 2.021.205.09.34.275.352.483.045.78.838 1.505 1.69 1.54.233.01.439.137.54.33.024.048.052.094.084.14l.04.057c.44.58 1.35.878 2.077.641a.656.656 0 01.621.111c.327.269.773.392 1.209.386.457.006.886-.117 1.213-.386a.658.658 0 01.415-.144zm-1.603-1.074a6.91 6.91 0 01-2.504-.455 6.302 6.302 0 01-2.003-1.24 5.777 5.777 0 01-1.352-1.84 5.344 5.344 0 01-.496-2.255c0-.782.167-1.539.496-2.254a5.73 5.73 0 011.352-1.838 6.402 6.402 0 012.003-1.241A6.767 6.767 0 019.022 1.6c.852 0 1.681.153 2.458.455a6.301 6.301 0 012.003 1.24 5.823 5.823 0 011.352 1.84c.33.712.496 1.47.496 2.253 0 .782-.167 1.539-.496 2.254a5.453 5.453 0 01-.539.924 6 6 0 01-.813.916 6.387 6.387 0 01-2.006 1.241 6.734 6.734 0 01-2.117.447c-.112.004-.224.008-.338.008z"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What could I be doing wrong here, the parent is `relative` the child elements are `absolute` and the parent is set to `h-full`, I would except the parent to grow automatically?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with tailwindcss, but removing "absolute" on the img itself seems to be the easy fix. Putting "absolute" on the img removes it from the flow, so it won't affect the height of the div that contains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }  
        .bg-gray-200.absolute.h-full {
            position: relative;
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
        } 
        .fill-current {
            margin-top: 4px;
        }
        .bg-second.absolute {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="rounded-lg overflow-hidden mb-6 cursor-pointer bg-white h-auto" style="box-shadow: lightgrey 4px 4px 12px;">
                    <div class="no-underline text-black overflow-hidden h-full relative"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/06181326/Shikoku-standing-outdoors.jpg" class="bg-gray-200 absolute h-full">
                        <div class="w-12 h-12 bg-second absolute">
                            <div>
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                    <path d="M6.642 15.096c-.5 0-1-.132-1.43-.37-.108-.061-.21-.135-.306-.198a2.394 2.394 0 01-.24-.205c-.057-.057-.336-.478-.38-.48a2.729 2.729 0 01-1.846-.994l-2.4 4.359c-.125.228.078.494.354.463l3.075-.344 1.565 2.505c.139.223.488.214.614-.014l2.442-4.432a2.51 2.51 0 01-.758-.38c-.22.059-.45.09-.69.09zm8.913-2.247c-.082.1-.174.195-.272.285a2.701 2.701 0 01-1.576.707c-.043.004-.32.425-.38.482-.118.113-.246.205-.388.31-.05.021-.102.063-.157.092a2.956 2.956 0 01-1.43.374c-.24 0-.473-.032-.69-.093-.22.164-.477.292-.758.38l2.442 4.432c.125.228.477.237.614.014l1.565-2.505 3.074.344c.277.031.48-.235.354-.463l-2.398-4.359zm-1.926-2.685c.183-.256.34-.527.47-.808a4.69 4.69 0 000-3.933 4.995 4.995 0 00-1.18-1.605 5.567 5.567 0 00-1.75-1.084 5.888 5.888 0 00-2.197-.396c-.743 0-1.465.134-2.143.396a5.493 5.493 0 00-1.75 1.084A5.063 5.063 0 003.9 5.423a4.69 4.69 0 000 3.933 5.02 5.02 0 001.18 1.608 5.568 5.568 0 001.75 1.084 5.876 5.876 0 001.846.39c.214.01.431.01.646 0a5.876 5.876 0 001.848-.39 5.493 5.493 0 001.75-1.084 5.3 5.3 0 00.71-.8zM9.442 4.688c.197-.625.793-1.015 1.332-.872.539.142.815.765.619 1.39-.196.624-.793 1.014-1.332.872-.537-.143-.815-.766-.619-1.39zm-2.218-.872c.54-.143 1.135.247 1.332.872.196.624-.082 1.247-.62 1.39-.538.142-1.134-.248-1.33-.873-.2-.624.08-1.247.618-1.39zM5.107 7.417c-.268-.601-.064-1.247.454-1.442.519-.195 1.156.136 1.426.738.267.601.064 1.247-.455 1.442-.518.195-1.156-.136-1.425-.738zm5.242 2.954c-.818-.205-1.754-.18-2.579-.025l-.119.025c-.438.11-1.434-.073-1.235-.914.198-.84 1.075-.805 1.315-1.937.071-.333.236-.663.546-.864.304-.197.713-.247 1.07-.16.267.066.5.217.66.424.136.179.216.388.262.6.24 1.134 1.117 1.096 1.316 1.937.196.84-.8 1.023-1.236.914zm1.117-2.216c-.518-.195-.724-.84-.454-1.442.267-.602.904-.933 1.425-.738.518.195.724.84.454 1.442-.27.602-.906.933-1.425.738z"></path>
                                    <path d="M10.625 14.252c.069 0 .14.01.208.033.804.262 1.837-.132 2.2-.838.1-.195.306-.321.54-.33.851-.035 1.644-.76 1.69-1.54a.562.562 0 01.351-.483c.77-.337 1.197-1.285.91-2.02a.537.537 0 01.127-.583c.576-.579.576-1.606.01-2.187a.532.532 0 01-.124-.57c.286-.738-.144-1.686-.914-2.02a.571.571 0 01-.358-.494c-.018-.356-.203-.742-.544-1.054a1.85 1.85 0 00-1.135-.497.614.614 0 01-.525-.323c-.167-.319-.496-.608-.935-.776a2.107 2.107 0 00-.742-.14c-.187 0-.366.027-.528.08a.685.685 0 01-.637-.118C9.933.151 9.502 0 9.022 0h-.05c-.48 0-.91.15-1.195.392a.663.663 0 01-.635.117c-.16-.052-.34-.08-.528-.08-.24 0-.493.045-.742.141-.439.168-.768.455-.934.776a.62.62 0 01-.526.323 1.85 1.85 0 00-1.135.497c-.34.312-.525.698-.544 1.054a.58.58 0 01-.358.495c-.77.333-1.2 1.28-.914 2.019a.532.532 0 01-.123.57c-.57.58-.567 1.608.009 2.187.157.159.205.381.128.582-.288.736.139 1.684.909 2.021.205.09.34.275.352.483.045.78.838 1.505 1.69 1.54.233.01.439.137.54.33.024.048.052.094.084.14l.04.057c.44.58 1.35.878 2.077.641a.656.656 0 01.621.111c.327.269.773.392 1.209.386.457.006.886-.117 1.213-.386a.658.658 0 01.415-.144zm-1.603-1.074a6.91 6.91 0 01-2.504-.455 6.302 6.302 0 01-2.003-1.24 5.777 5.777 0 01-1.352-1.84 5.344 5.344 0 01-.496-2.255c0-.782.167-1.539.496-2.254a5.73 5.73 0 011.352-1.838 6.402 6.402 0 012.003-1.241A6.767 6.767 0 019.022 1.6c.852 0 1.681.153 2.458.455a6.301 6.301 0 012.003 1.24 5.823 5.823 0 011.352 1.84c.33.712.496 1.47.496 2.253 0 .782-.167 1.539-.496 2.254a5.453 5.453 0 01-.539.924 6 6 0 01-.813.916 6.387 6.387 0 01-2.006 1.241 6.734 6.734 0 01-2.117.447c-.112.004-.224.008-.338.008z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-col pt-4">
                        <div class="flex px-4">
                            <div class="flex flex-col items-center w-1/6 mr-2">
                                <a href="#"><img src="https://sayhi.dog/profile.png" class="lozad bg-gray-400 bg-cover w-12 h-12 rounded-full shadow-lg z-50 m-2 zoom"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="px-2 pt-2 w-5/6">
                                <header class="flex flex-col">
                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between"><a href="#" class="font-bold text-black no-underline">
                                            Jamie
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://sayhidog.test/og/post/221" target="_blank" class="flex my-2 rounded text-sm">
                                            <p class="flex items-center text-facebook font-bold"><span class="hidden md:flex">Deel</span>
                                                <div class="w-4 h-4 fill-current ml-2">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                            <path d="M5.08 12.16A2.99 2.99 0 0 1 0 10a3 3 0 0 1 5.08-2.16l8.94-4.47a3 3 0 1 1 .9 1.79L5.98 9.63a3.03 3.03 0 0 1 0 .74l8.94 4.47A2.99 2.99 0 0 1 20 17a3 3 0 1 1-5.98-.37l-8.94-4.47z"></path>
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </p>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <!---->
                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between my-1">
                                        <div class="flex items-center">
                                            <div class="w-4 h-4 mr-1 fill-current text-gray-700">
                                                <div>
                                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                        <path d="M1 4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h14a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4zm2 2v12h14V6H3zm2-6h2v2H5V0zm8 0h2v2h-2V0zM5 9h2v2H5V9zm0 4h2v2H5v-2zm4-4h2v2H9V9zm0 4h2v2H9v-2zm4-4h2v2h-2V9zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2z"></path>
                                                    </svg>
                                                </div>
                                            </div> <span class="text-xs text-gray-600">

                                            </span></div>
                                        <!---->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex items-center my-1">
                                        <div class="w-4 h-4 mr-1 fill-current text-gray-700">
                                            <div>
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                    <path d="M10 20S3 10.87 3 7a7 7 0 1 1 14 0c0 3.87-7 13-7 13zm0-11a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z"></path>
                                                </svg>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> <a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=51.3234,4.94846" target="_blank" class="text-xs text-gray-600">
                                            Amsterdam
                                        </a></div>
                                </header>
                                <article class="py-4 text-black">
                                    Lekker lopen op de wei van mijn paardjes
                                </article>
                                <footer class="flex text-sm border-t">
                                    <div class="block flex px-4 py-2 items-center">
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="w-6 h-6 fill-current hover:text-red-500 cursor-pointer zoom text-gray-500">
                                                <div>
                                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                        <path d="M10 3.22l-.61-.6a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78 7.77L10 18.78l8.39-8.4a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78-7.77l-.61.61z"></path>
                                                    </svg>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> <span class="ml-2">2</span></div>
                                    <div class="block flex px-4 py-2 items-center group cursor-pointer">
                                        <div class="w-6 h-6 fill-current text-gray-500 group-hover:text-gray-700 zoom">
                                            <div>
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                    <path d="M17 11v3l-3-3H8a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h10a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v7a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-1zm-3 2v2a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H6l-3 3v-3H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h2v3a4 4 0 0 0 4 4h6z"></path>
                                                </svg>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> <span class="ml-2">0 reacties</span></div>
                                </footer>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!---->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="rounded-lg overflow-hidden mb-6 cursor-pointer bg-white h-auto" style="box-shadow: lightgrey 4px 4px 12px;">
                    <div class="no-underline text-black overflow-hidden h-full relative"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/06181326/Shikoku-standing-outdoors.jpg" class="bg-gray-200 absolute h-full">
                        <div class="w-12 h-12 bg-second absolute">
                            <div>
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                    <path d="M6.642 15.096c-.5 0-1-.132-1.43-.37-.108-.061-.21-.135-.306-.198a2.394 2.394 0 01-.24-.205c-.057-.057-.336-.478-.38-.48a2.729 2.729 0 01-1.846-.994l-2.4 4.359c-.125.228.078.494.354.463l3.075-.344 1.565 2.505c.139.223.488.214.614-.014l2.442-4.432a2.51 2.51 0 01-.758-.38c-.22.059-.45.09-.69.09zm8.913-2.247c-.082.1-.174.195-.272.285a2.701 2.701 0 01-1.576.707c-.043.004-.32.425-.38.482-.118.113-.246.205-.388.31-.05.021-.102.063-.157.092a2.956 2.956 0 01-1.43.374c-.24 0-.473-.032-.69-.093-.22.164-.477.292-.758.38l2.442 4.432c.125.228.477.237.614.014l1.565-2.505 3.074.344c.277.031.48-.235.354-.463l-2.398-4.359zm-1.926-2.685c.183-.256.34-.527.47-.808a4.69 4.69 0 000-3.933 4.995 4.995 0 00-1.18-1.605 5.567 5.567 0 00-1.75-1.084 5.888 5.888 0 00-2.197-.396c-.743 0-1.465.134-2.143.396a5.493 5.493 0 00-1.75 1.084A5.063 5.063 0 003.9 5.423a4.69 4.69 0 000 3.933 5.02 5.02 0 001.18 1.608 5.568 5.568 0 001.75 1.084 5.876 5.876 0 001.846.39c.214.01.431.01.646 0a5.876 5.876 0 001.848-.39 5.493 5.493 0 001.75-1.084 5.3 5.3 0 00.71-.8zM9.442 4.688c.197-.625.793-1.015 1.332-.872.539.142.815.765.619 1.39-.196.624-.793 1.014-1.332.872-.537-.143-.815-.766-.619-1.39zm-2.218-.872c.54-.143 1.135.247 1.332.872.196.624-.082 1.247-.62 1.39-.538.142-1.134-.248-1.33-.873-.2-.624.08-1.247.618-1.39zM5.107 7.417c-.268-.601-.064-1.247.454-1.442.519-.195 1.156.136 1.426.738.267.601.064 1.247-.455 1.442-.518.195-1.156-.136-1.425-.738zm5.242 2.954c-.818-.205-1.754-.18-2.579-.025l-.119.025c-.438.11-1.434-.073-1.235-.914.198-.84 1.075-.805 1.315-1.937.071-.333.236-.663.546-.864.304-.197.713-.247 1.07-.16.267.066.5.217.66.424.136.179.216.388.262.6.24 1.134 1.117 1.096 1.316 1.937.196.84-.8 1.023-1.236.914zm1.117-2.216c-.518-.195-.724-.84-.454-1.442.267-.602.904-.933 1.425-.738.518.195.724.84.454 1.442-.27.602-.906.933-1.425.738z"></path>
                                    <path d="M10.625 14.252c.069 0 .14.01.208.033.804.262 1.837-.132 2.2-.838.1-.195.306-.321.54-.33.851-.035 1.644-.76 1.69-1.54a.562.562 0 01.351-.483c.77-.337 1.197-1.285.91-2.02a.537.537 0 01.127-.583c.576-.579.576-1.606.01-2.187a.532.532 0 01-.124-.57c.286-.738-.144-1.686-.914-2.02a.571.571 0 01-.358-.494c-.018-.356-.203-.742-.544-1.054a1.85 1.85 0 00-1.135-.497.614.614 0 01-.525-.323c-.167-.319-.496-.608-.935-.776a2.107 2.107 0 00-.742-.14c-.187 0-.366.027-.528.08a.685.685 0 01-.637-.118C9.933.151 9.502 0 9.022 0h-.05c-.48 0-.91.15-1.195.392a.663.663 0 01-.635.117c-.16-.052-.34-.08-.528-.08-.24 0-.493.045-.742.141-.439.168-.768.455-.934.776a.62.62 0 01-.526.323 1.85 1.85 0 00-1.135.497c-.34.312-.525.698-.544 1.054a.58.58 0 01-.358.495c-.77.333-1.2 1.28-.914 2.019a.532.532 0 01-.123.57c-.57.58-.567 1.608.009 2.187.157.159.205.381.128.582-.288.736.139 1.684.909 2.021.205.09.34.275.352.483.045.78.838 1.505 1.69 1.54.233.01.439.137.54.33.024.048.052.094.084.14l.04.057c.44.58 1.35.878 2.077.641a.656.656 0 01.621.111c.327.269.773.392 1.209.386.457.006.886-.117 1.213-.386a.658.658 0 01.415-.144zm-1.603-1.074a6.91 6.91 0 01-2.504-.455 6.302 6.302 0 01-2.003-1.24 5.777 5.777 0 01-1.352-1.84 5.344 5.344 0 01-.496-2.255c0-.782.167-1.539.496-2.254a5.73 5.73 0 011.352-1.838 6.402 6.402 0 012.003-1.241A6.767 6.767 0 019.022 1.6c.852 0 1.681.153 2.458.455a6.301 6.301 0 012.003 1.24 5.823 5.823 0 011.352 1.84c.33.712.496 1.47.496 2.253 0 .782-.167 1.539-.496 2.254a5.453 5.453 0 01-.539.924 6 6 0 01-.813.916 6.387 6.387 0 01-2.006 1.241 6.734 6.734 0 01-2.117.447c-.112.004-.224.008-.338.008z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-col pt-4">
                        <div class="flex px-4">
                            <div class="flex flex-col items-center w-1/6 mr-2">
                                <a href="#"><img src="https://sayhi.dog/profile.png" class="lozad bg-gray-400 bg-cover w-12 h-12 rounded-full shadow-lg z-50 m-2 zoom"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="px-2 pt-2 w-5/6">
                                <header class="flex flex-col">
                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between"><a href="#" class="font-bold text-black no-underline">
                                            Jamie
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://sayhidog.test/og/post/221" target="_blank" class="flex my-2 rounded text-sm">
                                            <p class="flex items-center text-facebook font-bold"><span class="hidden md:flex">Deel</span>
                                                <div class="w-4 h-4 fill-current ml-2">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                            <path d="M5.08 12.16A2.99 2.99 0 0 1 0 10a3 3 0 0 1 5.08-2.16l8.94-4.47a3 3 0 1 1 .9 1.79L5.98 9.63a3.03 3.03 0 0 1 0 .74l8.94 4.47A2.99 2.99 0 0 1 20 17a3 3 0 1 1-5.98-.37l-8.94-4.47z"></path>
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </p>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <!---->
                                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between my-1">
                                        <div class="flex items-center">
                                            <div class="w-4 h-4 mr-1 fill-current text-gray-700">
                                                <div>
                                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                        <path d="M1 4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h14a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4zm2 2v12h14V6H3zm2-6h2v2H5V0zm8 0h2v2h-2V0zM5 9h2v2H5V9zm0 4h2v2H5v-2zm4-4h2v2H9V9zm0 4h2v2H9v-2zm4-4h2v2h-2V9zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2z"></path>
                                                    </svg>
                                                </div>
                                            </div> <span class="text-xs text-gray-600">

                                            </span></div>
                                        <!---->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex items-center my-1">
                                        <div class="w-4 h-4 mr-1 fill-current text-gray-700">
                                            <div>
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                    <path d="M10 20S3 10.87 3 7a7 7 0 1 1 14 0c0 3.87-7 13-7 13zm0-11a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z"></path>
                                                </svg>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> <a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=51.3234,4.94846" target="_blank" class="text-xs text-gray-600">
                                            Amsterdam
                                        </a></div>
                                </header>
                                <article class="py-4 text-black">
                                    Lekker lopen op de wei van mijn paardjes
                                </article>
                                <footer class="flex text-sm border-t">
                                    <div class="block flex px-4 py-2 items-center">
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="w-6 h-6 fill-current hover:text-red-500 cursor-pointer zoom text-gray-500">
                                                <div>
                                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                        <path d="M10 3.22l-.61-.6a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78 7.77L10 18.78l8.39-8.4a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78-7.77l-.61.61z"></path>
                                                    </svg>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> <span class="ml-2">2</span></div>
                                    <div class="block flex px-4 py-2 items-center group cursor-pointer">
                                        <div class="w-6 h-6 fill-current text-gray-500 group-hover:text-gray-700 zoom">
                                            <div>
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                                    <path d="M17 11v3l-3-3H8a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h10a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v7a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-1zm-3 2v2a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H6l-3 3v-3H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h2v3a4 4 0 0 0 4 4h6z"></path>
                                                </svg>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> <span class="ml-2">0 reacties</span></div>
                                </footer>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!---->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Piyush, the problem is that I have an absolute svg above the image. I don't see that now anymore. How could I make sure this SVG is above the image?

Comment: Hi Jenssen, svg  image check me

Comment: Thanks, but it should be above the image :) That's the problem, could you give it a try ?

Comment: Hi Jenssen, check me (image That's the problem)